# Multiple Filter to access nested JSON array

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, nested-loops, angular-filters

I have a `$filter` which filters a (un-nested)JSON file just fine by passing

```
filterMultiple:{dept:selectedDept,gender:selectedGender}
```

this behavior is replicated in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UiCandy/mro6pxa9/1/

I've made two entries in the JSON file which contain nested objects.

I want to be able to filter based on JSON data (One level deeper).
There is no need to check the existence of nested objects in every record as all the records will contain nested objects(Just like the first two in the JSON file), I've only added the other records to show that it works for un-nested objects.

I want my view to accept and filter values based on those nested objects:

```
filterMultiple:{details.name:some-Model}
```

However the filter does not accept 'foo.bar' or foo['bar'] notation.
So if someone can point me in the right direction, it would be a huge help.

What I tried:  To check `if(typeof(keyObj) == 'Object')` and then hook a recursive function to it, with little success or probably my implementation is wrong. Can someone try that in the fiddle?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: where U successful in it?